# WPF binding checkbox states to visibility of 2 seperate buttons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So I have this checkbox in WPF.

```
<CheckBox 

Name="folder_browser" Checked="{}" Unchecked="{}" 
Content="Folder browser" Foreground="Black" 
Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" 
Visibility="{Binding Visibility}">

</CheckBox>
```

I have to bind its checked and unchecked in such a way that with check, a certain button is visible and when unchecked, a different button. Both are separate buttons. The location of both is same on UI so I am getting confused.

Comment: You mean you have to Buttons on top of each other where always only one is visible? Why isn't it just one? You can change its Content according to the check state of the CheckBox, and perform different actions in its Click handler.

Comment: @Clemens Not just the content. I have to change between a file browsing button and a folder browsing button, depending on check state. I can do this with 1 button also but not sure if it's possible. I am new to WPF.

Comment: That's what I just wrote: *perform different actions in its Click handler*: `if (folder_browser.IsChecked == true) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: @Clemens Thank you. I will try this. Will update if it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever your view elements cannot have their property directly bind to source, then you need to implement a viewmodel as intermediate translator.
I made a simple demo WPF application for you. To repeate what I have done, create a new WPF application project named "CheckboxAndButtonVisibilityDemo", in MainWindow.xaml, copy following code:

```
<Window x:Name="window" x:Class="CheckboxAndButtonVisibilityDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CheckboxAndButtonVisibilityDemo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ViewModel.CheckBoxChecked, ElementName=window, Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
        <Button Visibility="{Binding ViewModel.ButtonAVisibility, ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}">ButtonA</Button>
        <Button Visibility="{Binding ViewModel.ButtonBVisibility, ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}">ButtonB</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Copy following code into MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace CheckboxAndButtonVisibilityDemo {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public ViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Add a new file, ViewModel.cs, and copy following code into it:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace CheckboxAndButtonVisibilityDemo {
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        private bool checkBoxChecked;
        public bool CheckBoxChecked {
            get { return checkBoxChecked; }
            set {
                checkBoxChecked = value;
                if (checkBoxChecked) {
                    ButtonAVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    ButtonBVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                } else {
                    ButtonAVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    ButtonBVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                }
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private Visibility buttonAVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        public Visibility ButtonAVisibility {
            get { return buttonAVisibility; }
            private set {
                buttonAVisibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private Visibility buttonBVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        public Visibility ButtonBVisibility {
            get { return buttonBVisibility; }
            private set {
                buttonBVisibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now its done, run and test it.

Comment: Hi. Thank for you for such in depth answer. I couldn't reply at that time!

Comment: But I am having an issue.

Comment: The propertychanged handler is giving an issue. It says "MainWindowViewModel.PropertyChanged' hides inherited member 'ObservableObject.PropertyChanged'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended"

Comment: I am following MVVM architecture in the app. And the switch is not happening whether box is unchecked or not. So I think the issue is with that handler.

Comment: @tcmsh your viewmodel should only inherit INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I am inheriting a different base model. Their are already some base getters and setters inside it. Is it possible to make changes inside that for notify?

Comment: @tcmsh Make a plain INotifyPropertyChanged class as an adaptor of that class.

Comment: @tcmsh Take note that view model is intermediate between model and view. Do not let your view directly databind to your model.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I got caught with some tasks.

Comment: Yes. I am binding with VM only. Will try creating INotifyPropertyChanged class inside the base model.

Comment: No, your VM should contain and adapt the model. The model should be independent to the VM. Don't any reference to instance of VM class in your model.

Comment: Hi. It's very rude to reply this late but I thought I should update. Someone else implemented the functionality by themselves, so I didn't have to do it. Right now I am gonna focus on WPF basics and MVVM, so that I don't get confused in basic stuff. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use a single Button and set its Content by a DataTrigger in a Button Style:

```
<Button Click="BrowseButtonClicked">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="File..."/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=folder_browser}"
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Folder..."/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

In the Click handler, perform different actions according to the check state of the CheckBox:

```
private void BrowseButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (folder_browser.IsChecked == true)
    {
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have the triggers set up already. Will try adding this to the handler and check if it works!